# edit list of printers in Batch

Tags: batch-file, printing, line

I'm trying to get a list of printers(maybe even the IP or port its using) from a remote PC, print to a text file and remove the blank lines and "name=" so it is just a list. In the end, I'll be using this list to create a re-image list along with the Ipconfig info it already picks up. I get that currently, it's running on the local machine.

PrinterList.bat

```
@echo off
wmic printer get name /value > print.txt
for /f %%a in (print.txt) do (
echo %%a
)

rem findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"^\ *$" "print.txt" >> "print.txt"
rem findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"^\ *$" /c:"^\*$" "print.txt" >> "print.txt"
)
pause
```

The Commented out lines are already tried samples from the web, tailored to the specific txt file

Output of print.txt - "<>" being a blank line with no spaces

```
<>
<>
Name=Send To OneNote 2016
<>
Name=WebEx Document Loader
<>
Name=Ricoh m306
```

Ideal Output of print.txt

```
Send To OneNote 2016
WebEx Document Loader
Ricoh m306
```

I'm working on doing the same for finding getting a list of installed programs of a remote PC.

I'd also like to edit the results of mapped drive.txt to later remap based on the output
Mapped drives are stored to a txt file locally

```
:smd
net use >> .\userSettings\%computername%_%username%_map.txt
Goto :HOME
```

Output of %computername%_%username%_map.txt:

```
New connections will be remembered.
<>
<>
Status       Local     Remote                    Network
<>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           H:        \\abc.abcde.abcdef.edu\home_folders\username 
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
             S:        \\ab.abcdef.org\share   Microsoft Windows Network
OK           X:        \\sgdm-group\packages      Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Y:        \\sgdm-group\upload        Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

I'd like to get it down to a list of drives and letter to map it to, that way I can `for /f %%a in (%computername%_%username%_map.txt) do (` from each line and `net use` to remap them later

Comment: Only ask single questions matching your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wmic output needs special parsing to remove cr,cr,lf sequences:

```
@Echo off
( for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in (
    'wmic printer get name /value ^|find "Name"'
  ) Do for /f "Delims=" %%B in ("%%A") Do Echo %%B
)>"print.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped majorly with both parts.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the special parsing necessary for the LF and CRs, there are usually unwanted spaces padded onto each output printer name item. For this reason in a simple structured script like yours I'd use a `Call` command to remove that padding.

```bat
@Echo Off
(Type Nul)>"print.txt"
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC /Node:"RemotePC-Name" Printer Get Name'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
(Echo=%*)>>"print.txt"
```

*You would obviosly replace `"RemotePC-Name"` with the "Name" or IPAddress of your remote PC.*